# gcc 8.2.0 build fails on LFS v8.3

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-from-scratch

While building all packages in order every single one of them has succeeded but gcc 8.2.0 build fails.

Below is the build error on executing `make`:

> msgfmt: error while loading shared libraries: libxml2.so.2: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: If `libxml2.so.2` exists on your system, then your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` doesn't contain a path to it? Do you have gcc 8.2 installed in parallel with an earlier version?

Comment: If you're familiar with LFS, I am on Chapter 6 where I reinstall it after chrooting.

Comment: Here is the output of version-check.sh https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4sbQMTn5rg/ . You may find here that I have the same version of gcc installed.

Comment: Looking [LFS - 6. Installing Basic System Software](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter06/chapter06.html), libxml2 isn't listed to be installed, but `XML::Parser-2.44` is. Just a guess, but I suspect one of the packages you are attempting to install has a dependency for `libxml2`. Have you tried installing `libxml2`? That seems like the next logical step -- otherwise you have the tedious task of finding which package is looking for that dependency. Seems like any `./configure` file should detect whether it is an unmet requirement.